# Type alias or full namespace

Tags: c#

Does it affect performance to use type alias rather than full namespace?
For example, import just `Form` class
`using Form = System.Windows.Forms.Form;`
or import all types
`using System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543107/c-sharp-using-namespace-statement-ordering

Comment: No, my question is not about `using` order

Comment: Note: I didn't vote to close this as a dupe. The question I linked to is in the same vein as this question (using decls and relation to perf) and I thought it may also be worth a read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this has absolutely no affect on the performance of your application.  This could in theory have an affect on compilation time.  But it would almost certainly be insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

No both have exactly the same performance, it's just personal preference - it gets compiled down to the same exact code.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference - it is resolved by compiler before it runs.

Answer (score 0):

No. None whatsoever at runtime (the binaries produced are identical), and the compile-time impact is literally negligible.